# How to create 2 unique Headers with complete different navigations on Venture Free Theme of shopify?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I just want to ask the community if you have any idea, how to create a unique header for a specific page on shopify.

Theme is Venture(Free Version)

I want to have UK page and US page on my shopify store. My index page is UK based or international clients. While the US page is for US customers only. I want to have a different header and navigation for US page since there are products that are not available for US customers. I just want to post US only products.

Anyone can help me with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This will require more than just a header change, but it is possible to have two separate headers.

However, the localization may be tricky.

According to [Shopify docs](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/markets/languages#limitations-of-selling-in-multiple-languages):

> Your theme's primary language cannot be a regional variant when using
> Shopify Markets. For example, you should not change your primary
> language to English (United States). It should be English.

*This can be done by assigning an array of IP addresses to an variable that is placed in several conditionals.*

This process is *far* too advanced for laymen. If you are not comfortable with liquid and javscript, You can use [Nosto](https://www.nosto.com/) or the app Geo-targeting.

If you are looking to do this yourself, please refer to the docs regarding the ‘browsing_context_suggestions.json’ endpoint.
This will then need to be compared to an array of some sort that will assign your customers to a region.
Then, assign that endpoint to a variable and use that variable as a conditional to display your menu with:

```
{% assign menu = [british menu] %}
```

*I know how to do this, so if you need help I can set it up. It just won't be free, and I recommend trying the apps before you hire unless you are scaled properly for development.*

**You will then need to lock your products by region**, which is done in ruby. You have limited access to ruby through liquid, and backend editing of this sort requires an app. You cannot region lock products in front end without a ton of work and it will be extremely unstable, expensive, and will not lock search results regionally.

**So try [Locksmith](https://apps.shopify.com/locksmith) to region lock products.** I haven't used it, so my suggestion is blind there, and some experimentation may be required.